# Pydantic/SQLAlchemy: How to work with enums?

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy, pydantic

What is the best way to convert a sqlalchemy model to a pydantic schema (model) if it includes an enum field?

Sqlalchemy

```py
import enum
from sqlalchemy import Enum, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class StateEnum(enum.Enum):
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    UPDATED = 'UPDATED'

class Adapter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'adapters'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    friendly_name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    state: StateEnum = Column(Enum(StateEnum))
```

Pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

class StateEnumDTO(str, Enum):
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    UPDATED = 'UPDATED'


class AdapterDTO(BaseModel):
    friendly_name: str
    state: StateEnumDTO  # This currently cannot be converted?

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        orm_mode = True
        use_enum_values = True
```

Conversion

```py
AdapterDTO.from_orm(Adapter(friendly_name='test', state=StateEnum.CREATED))
```

This leads to the error

`value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'CREATED', 'UPDATED' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<StateEnumDTO.CREATED: 'CREATED'>, <StateEnumDTO.UPDATED: 'UPDATED'>])`

How can I configure either

a.) the serialization with the from_orm method?

or

b.) the creation of the `state` field?

c.) How to convert it the other way around?

Is there a native way to do this with pydantic or how is this typically done?

Update:
Test case

```
def test_enum_conversion_to_dto():
    adapter = Adapter(id='1', friendly_name='test', state=StateEnum.CREATED)
    adapter_dto = AdapterDTO.from_orm(adapter)
    assert adapter_dto.state == StateEnumDTO.CREATED
    assert adapter_dto.state.value == StateEnum.CREATED.value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pydantic requires that both enum classes have the same type definition.

In your case, `StateEnum` inherits from `enum.Enum`, but `StateEnumDTO` inherits from both `str` and `enum.Enum`.

You can fix this issue by changing your SQLAlchemy enum definition:

```
class StateEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    UPDATED = 'UPDATED'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `arbitrary_types_allowed = True`
To the model Config class.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

class StateEnumDTO(str, Enum):
    CREATED = 'CREATED'
    UPDATED = 'UPDATED'


class AdapterDTO(BaseModel):
    friendly_name: str
    state: StateEnumDTO  # This currently cannot be converted?

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        orm_mode = True
        use_enum_values = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

Comment: Sadly this seems not to work. I will add a test case.

Comment: @E.ws What version of pydantic? The above code is for < 2.0.